# Extend observableArray with data from a second source

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i create an observableArray from an Ajax Source which is working pretty well. Now I want to extend some of the array items with data from a second source.

For example:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Hugo', age: 18 }
```

... later I want to add:

```
{ id: 1, city: 'New York', country: 'US' }
```

... which should result in:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Hugo', age: 18, city: 'New York', country: 'US' }
```

Is this possible with the ko.mapping plugin? I already did some tests with the result that the mapped properties of the items in the array have been replaced by properties from the second source.

---

**Solution**

Well, it was actually pretty easy to solve. When adding the new data with the mapping plugin I just have to check for the `key`. The existing data is just extended with the additional data.

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(modifications, {
    key: function(data) {
        return ko.unwrap(data.id);
    }
}, originalData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the properties aren't observables you can use ko.utils.extend.

```
var original = { id: 1, name: 'Hugo', age: 18 };
var modifications ={ id: 1, city: 'New York', country: 'US' };


var result2 =  ko.utils.extend(original,  modifications);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result2));
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nnnW/)